# Set up SMS MFA for users but getting null value

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, active-directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

We are implementing MFA for all users in our enterprise (around 5k users). A condition from management is however that the users doesnt have to configure anything by themselfs (most users are factory workers and dont have own laptops etc). So our train of though was to add SMS option to them even tho its not the most optimal but would make it so we can set it up for them using a script - we thought atleast.

We made a PS script that should look through a given userlist and check if they have MFA enabled and a phone number. If they dont have MFA enabled and have a Phone number, it should add the MFA method SMS using the phoneNumber parameter. Everything works - except we get "NULL" value as the phone number set for all users.

Would like feedback on why the script isnt working as it should! We have a hybrid onprem Azure environment

```
Connect-MsolService
    $csv=Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\userlist.csv" 
    $csv | % {
        $upn=$_.UserPrincipalName
        $user=$null
        $user=Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $upn
        $mfaresult=""
        $mfa=$null
        $mfa=$user.StrongAuthenticationMethods
        $mfa | % {
            If ($_.isDefault -eq "True") {$mfaresult=$_.MethodType }     
        }
        $phonenumber=""
        $phonenumber=$user.phonenumber
        If (($mfaresult.Length -eq "") -and ($phonenumber.Length -gt 0)) {
            $SMS = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationMethod
            $SMS.IsDefault = $true
            $SMS.MethodType = "OneWaySMS"
            Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $upn -StrongAuthenticationMethods $SMS
        }
    }
```

Add users in pilot group - run script - grab the phone number properties and add that number as SMS MFA method

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the specifics of Microsoft azure, if it’s like c# I can understand setting the user variable to null, because c# is a strictly typed language. However just a beginners guess would be to check if user or phone number (whichever variable isn’t storing its value correctly) needs to be initialized to null. If not maybe don’t init it and see if the result is different